# pandas build a new column by list boolean

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to build two new columns by list boolean. This is for mobile data classification.

sample data:

```
mobile_phone
85295649956
85398745632
8612345678945
34512654
```

There is my code:

```
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',delimiter='|',dtype = str)

a = r'852[4-9]|853[4-9]|86'

print(list(map(lambda x: bool(re.match(a, x)), df['mobile_phone'])))
```

Now my response is:

```
[True,True,True,False]
```

I can list the boolean but I don't know how can I use this.

I tried something like this:

```
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',delimiter='|',dtype = str)

a = r'852[4-9]|853[4-9]|86'
df['mobile'] = np.where(
     (lambda x: bool(re.match(a, x)), df['mobile_phone']) = True
    ,df['mobile_phone']
    ,nan
)
df['phone'] = np.where(
     (lambda x: bool(re.match(a, x)), df['mobile_phone']) = True,
    nan,
    df['mobile_phone']

)
```

I tried to use `np.where` but this can't work. Because this show me the error  `keyword can't be an experession`

How can I show the result like this?

Desired result:

```
mobile_phone           mobile        phone
85295649956       85295649956          nan
85398745632       85398745632          nan
8612345678945   8612345678945          nan
34512654                  nan     34512654
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to process your values into new columns. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({'mobile_phone': ['85295649956', '85398745632', '8612345678945', '34512654', '54861245'] })

a = r'852[4-9]|853[4-9]|86'
df['mobile'] = df['mobile_phone'].apply(lambda p: p if re.match(a, p) else math.nan)
df['phone'] = df['mobile_phone'].apply(lambda p: math.nan if re.match(a, p) else p)
df
```

Output:

```
    mobile_phone         mobile     phone
0    85295649956    85295649956      NaN
1    85398745632    85398745632      NaN
2  8612345678945  8612345678945      NaN
3       34512654           NaN       34512654
4       54861245           NaN       54861245
```